# Use Same MapInstance in Multiple Activities without loading again

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

I need to save an i**nstance of a mapView** fragment with all the markers and cameraPosition so that I can show it to the user after he go to another activity **without loading Map again**. Is there any way to save it complete map instance and just attach to MapView Again.

Comment: Means do you want to capture snap shot of Map?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot transfer a View (MapView being one) between Activities because Views are coupled with Activity lifecycle. And Google [says](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html):

> You cannot instantiate a GoogleMap object directly, rather, you must obtain one from the getMap() method on a MapFragment or MapView that you have added to your application

So there goes your hope. What you can do however is transfer the data used on the map. You can serialize your data, put it in Intent as String or Parcelable, retrieve the Intent in the next Activity, and deserialize it.